# Do computer/cpu really understand(binary)?

Tags: cpu, cpu-architecture

I have read and heard from many people,books, sites computer understand nothing but only binary!But they dont tell how computer/cpu  understand binary.So I was thinking how can computer/cpu can understand?Cause as of my little knowledge and thinking, to think or understand something one must need a brain and off-course a life but cpu lack both.

*`*Additionally as cpu run by electricity, so my guess is cpu understand nothing,not even binary rather  there are some natural rules for electricity or something like that and  we human*`*(or who invented computer) `found it`(may be if we flow current in a certain combination or in certain number of circuits we get a row light or like so, who know!) `and also a way to manipulate the current flow/straight light to make with it, what we need i.e different letters`(with straight three light or magnetic wave occurred from the electricity with the help of manipulation we can have letter 'A') `means computer/cpu dont understanad anything.`

Its just my wild guess. I hope someone could help me to have a clear idea about if cpu really understand anything(binary)?And if, then how. Anyone detailed answer,article or book would be great.Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://hashnode.com/post/how-does-a-computer-machine-understand-0s-and-1s-civgqet5609xwxr53q0chkbbg

Comment: @Ville-Valtteri Thanks its a big help! But a more easy to understand answer would be appreciated.

Comment: @ Ville-Valtteri i pretty much got my answer after reading the whole article. Would you mind writing the link as a answer? i would like to accept it as a answer and its detailed too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From HashNode article ["How does a computer machine understand 0s and 1s?"](https://hashnode.com/post/how-does-a-computer-machine-understand-0s-and-1s-civgqet5609xwxr53q0chkbbg)

> A computer doesn't actually "understand" anything. It merely provides you with a way of information flow — input to output. The decisions to transform a given set of inputs to an output (computations) are made using boolean expressions (expressed using specific arrangements of logic gates).
>
> At the hardware level we have bunch of elements called transistors (modern computers have billions of them and we are soon heading towards an era where they would become obsolete). These transistors are basically switching devices. Turning ON and OFF based on supply of voltage given to its input terminal. If you translate the presence of voltage at the input of the transistor as 1 and absence of voltage as 0 (you can do it other way too). There!! You have the digital language.

Answer (score 0):

"understand" no.  Computers don't *understand* anything, they're just machines that operate according to fixed rules for moving from one state to another.

But all these states are encoded in binary.

So if you anthropomorphise the logical (architectural) or physical (out-of-order execution, etc. etc.) operation of a computer, you might use the word "understand" as a metaphor for "process" / "operate in".

Taking this metaphor to the extreme, one toy architecture is called the [Little Man Computer, LMC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_man_computer), named for the conceit / joke idea that there is a little man inside the vastly simplified CPU actually doing the binary operations.

> The LMC model is based on the concept of a little man shut in a closed mail room (analogous to a computer in this scenario). At one end of the room, there are 100 mailboxes (memory), numbered 0 to 99, that can each contain a 3 digit instruction or data (ranging from 000 to 999).

So actually, LMC is based around a CPU that "understands" decimal, unlike a normal computer.

The LMC toy architecture is terrible to program for except for the very simplest of programs.  It doesn't support left/right bit-shifts or bitwise binary operations, which makes sense because it's based on decimal not binary.  (You can of course double a number = left shift by adding to itself, but right shift needs other tricks.)

Comment: Noted. Will make sure to read more about LMC. Looks like it will be interesting to read! Thanks

Comment: @Tanzin: another toy architecture that's more normal (based on binary, not decimal) is LC3.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LC-3.  LC-3b (which includes a right shift) can be programmed efficiently for most things, without having to jump through ridiculous hoops.  The main things it's lacking vs. a modern CPU are multiply and divide in hardware.  Modern CPUs have very high performance integer multiply, so having to use a shift-and-add loop is pretty terrible.